# calculate the title height and if the title height is above some number then add some space

Tags: pdftex, calculations, lengths, calc

calculate the title height and if the title height is above some number then add some space.

> when I use the code get the title, but when I use code like this \settoheight{\heightoftitle}{\vbox{\title{Hello}}} title become empty

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\heightoftitle}
\settoheight{\heightoftitle}{\vbox{Hello }}
Value = \the\heightoftitle
\end{document}
```

> when I use the following coding I didn't get the exact height of the title

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\settominwidth}[1]{\saltyegg@settomin{\wd}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settominheight}[1]{\saltyegg@settomin{\ht}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settominheights}[1]{\saltyegg@settomin{\ht}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settomindepth}[1]{\saltyegg@settomin{\dp}{#1}}

\newcommand{\saltyegg@settomin}[3]{%
  #2\maxdimen
  \@for\next:=#3\do{%
    \sbox\z@{\next}%
    \ifdim#1\z@<#2%
      #2=#1\z@
    \fi}%
}
\makeatother

\newlength{\saltyeggtest}

\begin{document}
\title{sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title\settominheight{\saltyeggtest}{sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title}\the\saltyeggtest}
\maketitle
%makte

\settominwidth{\saltyeggtest}{a,b,c,f}
\the\saltyeggtest

\settominheight{\saltyeggtest}{sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title sample title }
\the\saltyeggtest 


\settomindepth{\saltyeggtest}{a,b,c,f}
\the\saltyeggtest

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me which problem you have with the first example. Concerning the second one, your `\sbox\z@{\next}` composes the text in `\next` in restricted horizontal mode  (what LaTeX calls LR-mode). So, you always measure the width, height or depth of a *single line,* no matter how many words you put therein. You can't measure the height of what `\maketitle` produces this way, because with `\maketitle`, the title is broken accross lines, which implies that it is *not* composed in restricted horizontal mode. In order to measure that, you have to precisely analyse how `\maketitle` works.